# Storing URL's in Environment variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I'm trying to store URL's in my environment variables. So for instance

```
ENV['SET_COOKIE_URL'] = 'http://domain.com/setcookie'
```

In my application layout page, I'm trying to do this:

```
window.top.location = '<%= ENV["SET_COOKIE_URL"] %>';
```

When I try this, it always returns `''` (empty string).

Can you not store and output URL's in environment variables?

Comment: Do you mean you get the `''` in HTML? or the variable `window.top.location` as `''`

Comment: Also, if you just added this environment variable, perhaps re-starting your server would help pickup the environment change. I don't see any reason why you won't be able to use that environment variable in your view.

Comment: I mean if I do var url = '<%= ENV["SET_COOKIE_URL"] %>'; the outputted HTML is var url = '';

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Just restarted my server and they appear. So anytime you set an ENV variable or modify it, you need to restart the server? Feel free to post the answer and I'll accept it below.

Comment: Yep, all the Environment variables get stuck in the current process when you bootup your server. If you add more ENV variables, your process will not recognize them until you restart the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just added this environment variable, perhaps re-starting your server would help pickup the environment change. I don't see any reason why you won't be able to use that environment variable in your view other than just re-booting your server.